# Adding an overlay to cover the entire contents of the webpage

Tags: css

I was wondering if there is a way to create a black transparent overlay to basically cover the entire contents of the webpage?

```
<body>
  <div class="main-container">
    <!--many more divs here to create webpage-->
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: `.main-container { background: #000; opacity: 0.4; height: 100%; width: 100%;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this css on a div to create a black transparent overlay:

```
#overlay {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The very basic overlay can be made using position absolute:

```
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    opacity: .6;
    background-color: #000;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/4Mn7Q/

UPD. As GSP pointed in comment this is not optimal solution when window height is bigger then a viewport. In this case body `{position: relative;}` should be used as well.

Comment: I was about to answer with this one as well, but for me at least on FireFox thsi didn't work if the viewport was smaller than the window (i.e. there were scroll bars and the user scrolls down the page).

Comment: Right, this is the problem. In this case one should use position fixed or add `body {position: relative;}`

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you are looking for: http://malsup.com/jquery/block/